# Is testing an individual testcase necessary during automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an automation setup where I have my automation scripts integrated with GIT. When the new code is committed, the script will trigger automatically and run the regression.

Assume if the code change happens only in the login page and I need to validate that only not the entire automation scenario. If the module is integrated then I don't need this approach. But if the code change happens for the only individual model with the setup that I have, do I validate that change alone?

If yes, what is the advantage of validating that change alone instead of validating the entire scripts?

Comment: Re: "what is the advantage on validating that change alone instead validating the entire scripts?" It's a trade-off between test coverage and time you spend on testing. Having limited time, you usually try to prioritize tests from the most important to least important.

Answer (score 2):

So for me, once we have a change committed for a single module and manual testing has been completed, I would first run/trigger the smoke tests and then will trigger the in-depth tests related to that module only.

Yes, regression would still run the entire test suite (based on the trigger - daily/weekly etc.) irrespective of the changes because that's what we want automated tests to do, run on daily basis (in most of the cases) and provide results so that we can identity the issues as early as possible.